# Can you use Twinned Spell on Fireball and target the same creature with both attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, metamagic, targeting

Can a sorcerer use the Twinned Spell metamagic on the *fireball* spell and target the same creature with both attacks?

Also, if you can target one with both, would it be double damage?

Comment: Related: [When casting a spell using Twinned Spell does it use one or two spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64470/when-casting-a-spell-using-twinned-spell-does-it-use-one-or-two-spell-slots) (The body of the question specifically uses the *fireball* spell as an example, but the question itself is a different one.)

Answer (score 9):

No, for two reasons.

## Twinned Spell can't be used with *fireball*

The sorcerer's Twinned Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option has some restrictions on what spells it can be used with:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).
>
> **To be eligible, a spell must be incapable of targeting more than one creature at the spell’s current level.** For example, *magic missile* and *scorching ray* aren’t eligible, but *ray of frost* and *chromatic orb* are.

The description of the [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) spell says:

> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. **Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw.** A target takes 8d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

By definition, all area-of-effect spells (that I know of) are able to affect more than a single creature. Thus, AoE spells, including *fireball* can't generally be twinned.

(It's not just about whether the spell *does target* more than one creature; it's about whether the spell is *capable of targeting* more than one creature. *Fireball* is capable of targeting any number of creatures within its area of effect.)

## A Twinned Spell has to target two different creatures

As quoted above, from the description of Twinned Spell:

> When you cast a spell that targets only one creature and doesn’t have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell’s level to **target a second creature in range** with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

[Jeremy Crawford, official rules designer for 5e, confirms this on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/829087884955095040):

> *Hey, can twinned spell, target the same person twice?*
>
> **If a rule, such as Twinned Spell, says you affect one creature and then a second creature, those are two different creatures.**

Even if you could twin *fireball*, or no matter what other valid spell you use Twinned Spell on, you need to target two different creatures with the two instances of the spell. You can't target the same creature twice with a Twinned Spell.

## A minor note: *fireball* isn't an "attack"

[The basic rules define attacks very simply](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MakinganAttack):

> If there's ever any question whether something you're doing counts as an attack, the rule is simple: if you're making an attack roll, you're making an attack.

This includes both melee and ranged attacks, and both weapon and spell attacks. The only addition is that [grapples](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) and [shoves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) are described as "special melee attacks", even though they don't involve an attack roll. So something is only an attack if it involves an attack roll *or* if it is specifically described as an "attack".

*Fireball* doesn't involve an attack roll, and it's not described as an attack. It merely requires any affected foes to make a Dexterity saving throw to potentially halve the damage. As such, *fireball* is not an attack.

See this question for more details: [Do saving throw based spells that do damage count as attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65415/do-saving-throw-based-spells-that-do-damage-count-as-attacks)

Comment: I'm picturing an in-world lawyer defending someone for using a fireball in an attempted murder, and getting him off on a technicality because he's accused of 'attacking' his victim and Fireball isn't an attack.

Answer (score 7):

### No, you can't.

Twinned Spell:

> When you cast **a spell that targets only one creature** and doesn't have a range of self, you can spend a number of sorcery points equal to the spell's level to target a second creature in range with the same spell (1 sorcery point if the spell is a cantrip).

As I emphasized, the twinned spell must be a spell that targets only one creature and not an area spell like fireball.